MSVC rejects a template multiple argument operator []
Consider this minimized snippet:
struct Context
{
    template<class T> int operator[](int, T)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Context ctx;
    return ctx[0, 0];
}

I guess it is well-formed C++23 code. It compiles fine on latest GCC and Clang, but is rejected by the latest version of MSVC (19.42.34435, from Visual Studio 17.12.3).
Here is the compiler error:
1>test.cpp(15,20): error C2676: binary '[': 'Context' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1> test.cpp(6,27):
1>    could be 'int Context::operator [](int,T)'
1>  test.cpp(15,12):
1>     'initializing': cannot convert from 'Context' to 'int'
1>            test.cpp(15,12):
1>      No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Note that the support for C++23 multiple arguments of operator [] in MSVC is really new, introduced with Visual Studio 17.12. My guess is that it is a compiler bug, but before filling a bug report to Microsoft, I wish to be sure.

Not surprising as C++23 is largely not supported by msvc. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23

In row "Multidimensional subscript operator" you can see that MSVC didn't implement this language feature yet.

relevant? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-compiler-language-updates-in-visual-studio-2022-version-17-12/

@MarekR True, but I was assuming that the table was just not being updated yet, as the feature has been announced by Microsoft on December 6th only. Also, it works in other contexts.

@prapin you can see that 19.42 is mentioned in this table (formatting ranges). So this table covers your version of compiler.

Anaway here is MSVC official document saying: "P2128R6 Multidimensional subscript operator   no"

If the feature was release 10 days ago, it's quite possible it has bugs in it. Perhaps they didn't consider this case

Multi-argument operator[] is still on the roadmap but std::mdspan not working with [] operator that was closed as a dupe of the first one is closed as fixed in 17.12. :-)
